# Ubuntu showing incorrect battery percentage on MacBook Air (2011). Is it a bug?

Tags: laptop, power-management, battery, macbook-air

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on a 2011 MacBook Air (directly, not using virtualization), and the battery percentage seems off. I left the charger plugged in until the LED turned green, and yet the Ubuntu battery percentage indicator only showed 90% or so.

When I run `upower -i`, I see something like the following:

```
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               SMP
  model:                bq20z451
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Mon 25 Jul 2016 02:08:39 PM PDT (87 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              40.7775 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         43.71 Wh
    energy-full-design:  50.25 Wh
    energy-rate:         11.325 W
    voltage:             7.978 V
    time to empty:       3.6 hours
    percentage:          82%
    temperature:         32.6 degrees C
    capacity:            86.9851%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1469480919  82.000  discharging
  History (rate):
    1469480919  11.325  discharging
```

So clearly Ubuntu is seeing the right battery information here, but the battery percentage is obviously wrong (it's showing 82%, but it should show 93% because `energy/energy-full=0.932`).

It almost seems like a naive bug where the battery percentage is calculated as `energy/energy-full-design`, instead of `energy/energy-full`... Any ideas on how to get it to show the correct value?

Comment: There are different ways to calculate battery percentage remaing. This is how this software is doing it. :)